# decode lat lng values

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have an third party application which saves lat and lng values as below in the db.

```
  lat          lng          lat_dir    lng_dir

   2824.2311    07703.0962   N          E
```

The problem is, It is not clear on which unit lat lng values are saved in DB.

I have tried to convert in degree by assuming the values in KM. After  Lat comes some where nearby If I assume,But in no way lng comes. lng values is more away that I can assume.

Any Guidence is appreciated.

PS. I have no control over third party application, and there is no document present over lat lng calculation by third party application.

Comment: You need to find out the representation that the third party application is storing the data in.  Where is that point?  Is it south west of New Delhi?

Comment: @geocodezip : yes, it is south west of New Delhi. I donot have any control of third party application.Only I have db access.

Answer (score 0):

Google map requires the lat and lng to be in the decimal format. The format that the third party application is storing is used by some GPS tracking devices. I don't recall what the format is called though.

You will need to convert the lat / lng to decimal format before plotting it on the map. Given below is the Java code to convert it into a decimal format.

```
    private static String getCordinate(String location) {
        int len = location.length();
        String decimals = location.substring(len-7);
        Float decimalf = Float.parseFloat(decimals) / 60;
        String first = location.substring(0,len-7);
        Float coordinate = Float.parseFloat(first) + decimalf;
        return coordinate.toString();
    }
```

> Coordinate Format - Latitude : 1907.51672 & Longitude : 7252.34810
>
> Output Format : Latitude : 28.403852 & Longitude : 77.051605

The location is as follows on [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/28%C2%B024'13.9%22N+77%C2%B003'05.8%22E/@28.403852,77.0494163,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d28.403852!4d77.051605)